# Whenever I try to do a quad, I get "Invalid Selection Order"! What is that and how do I fix it?

Tags: objects

OK, so I am having this problem with quads. I was attempting to create an eyeball and cornea (Anyone else tried that tutorial? It's so confusing.) and one of the steps is to turn 16 segments into 8 quads. It's really easy to do. The first few times I did it, it worked fine. But when I got to another part it let me do three quads then it said "invalid selection order". I did it again. Same message. Sometimes it will just not let me do it period. If the pictures will pull up below, the you should see what I am working with and the message. Please give me an answer on how to let it let me do quads again! Thank you everyone! Have a blessed day!
   here is the link to the tutorial: https://cloud.blender.org/p/blenderella/56040ecf044a2a00a515ada7  I am at 16:30 - 17:25. THanks again!

[image: Here is the oject when I am working on it and I got the message]

Comment: Unfortunately I can't see any images. I tried to edit your post, in case you had made a mistake when adding them, but I only see two file names, without any URLs to suggest where you uploaded them. If for some reason you're unable to get the images inline, you can include the URLs to them instead.

Comment: It would be helpful if you edit a link to the tutorial into your question, with an indication of where in the tutorial you are having a problem.